# Make a label on the right and the left when change the language

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, right-to-left

How can set the label in the right and in the left when change the language in my application iOS?

```
if (language == arabic) {
    self.myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
} else if (language == english) {
    self.myLAbel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft; 
}
```

My problem with the test in `if else` condition.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that , the problem is with your condition.

> language && arabic || English --> NSString of type.

then,

```
if ([language isEqualToString:arabic]) // ([language isEqualToString:@"arabic"])
    self.myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
else
    self.myLAbel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

If this is not, then let me know the Type of these **language && arabic || English**.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
As per **@Kumar Kl's** answer if you want to string compare then **==** operator is not work .  you need use `[@"string1" isEqualToString:@"string2"]`.

If your have to choice language either arabic or english then no need  to set at last `else...if` only `else` is enough.

```
if (language==arabic)
    self.myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
else
    self.myLAbel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

In your code problem is when your language is neither  arabic nor a english in such case  of your code your `if...else if..`  condition is not work you need to put suclike

```
if (language==arabic)
        self.myLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
 else if (language==english)
        self.myLAbel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft; 
 else
     /// here you need to set your textAlignment as you want.
```